# Oracle SQL - SELECT query locks index & blocks DML sessions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, concurrency, oracle11g

We have some very weird locking happening in production. We have setup a PL/SQL script that finds objects that have been locked for more than 5 seconds and send us an alert e-mail.

Below is the cursor of that script:

```
select l.sid, trunc(l.id1 / power(2, 16)) rbs,
    bitand(l.id1, to_number('ffff', 'xxxx')) + 0 slot,
    l.id2, l.lmode, l.request, l.ctime, l.block,
    substr(v.osuser, 1, 12) osuser,
    substr(v.machine, 1, 15) machine,
    substr(v.module, 1, 12) module,
    decode(v.blocking_session_status||l.block, 'VALID0',
           dbms_rowid.rowid_create(1, v.row_wait_obj#, v.row_wait_file#,
                       v.row_wait_block#, v.row_wait_row#), '.') lrow,
    o.object_name,
    decode(v.sql_id, null, v.prev_sql_id, v.sql_id) sql_id,
    o.owner
from v$lock l, v$session v, all_objects o
where l.sid = v.sid
  and v.row_wait_obj# = o.object_id(+)
  and l.ctime > 5 and l.type = 'TX' and (l.request = 6 or l.block = 1)
order by 2, 3, 4, 8 desc, 7 desc;
```

And we got the alert today for a lock:

```
SID  TRANS-ID        L-TYPE  CTIME  BLOCK OSUSER     MACHINE         MODULE        SQLID            ROWID            OBJECT
---- --------------- ------- ------ ----- ---------- --------------- ------------ ------------- ------------------ --------------------
669  132,11,40475    6/0     70     1     userpr1     serv1023       userpr1-00002 fbnhs4gd9a7yn .                  IDX_005
1133 132,11,40475    0/6     62     0     userpr1     serv1023       userpr1-00000 f0gm2rx85qjja AAAgOuAAFAAD04TAAW ITEMST
924  132,11,40475    0/6     53     0     userpr1     serv1023       userpr1-00002 f0gm2rx85qjja AAAgOuAAFAAD04TAAW ITEMST
927  132,11,40475    0/6     27     0     userpr1     serv1023       userpr1-00001 f0gm2rx85qjja AAAgOuAAFAAD04TAAW ITEMST
```

So from the above, we can observe that sqlid `fbnhs4gd9a7yn` of session `669` has got a lock on index `IDX_005` and blocking the rest of the remaining sessions.

Now for the most bizarre part:

1. SQLID `fbnhs4gd9a7yn` is just a SELECT query (not even a SELECT FOR
   UPDATE)
2. The index `IDX_005` has no connection to table `ITEMST` but it blocks the remaining 3 sessions which updates `ITEMST` anyways

So my question is:
How did [1] happen and why does it block update to the table `ITEMST`?

Could this be an bug in Oracle?
We are using Oracle 11.2.0.4 Enterprise Edition, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sql_id` that your query returns may or may not be related to the query that actually acquired the lock.

In SID 669, for example, if I update `ITEMST` and then run a query but I haven't committed my `update`, you'd see that 669 is running a `SELECT` statement and that it holds a lock.  It was the earlier `UPDATE` (or `INSERT` or whatever) that the session had done that actually acquired the lock.  There just isn't an easy way to see what earlier query the session had done that acquired the lock that other sessions are now waiting on.

Comment: Thanks Justin, that makes sense. Actually, I checked ASH for session 669 for any SQL involving ITEMST before that locking was sampled, but I couldn't find any. Could it be that oracle just did not sample that session that involved the SQL that actually acquired the lock?

Comment: @toddlermenot - It is entirely possible, sure.  ASH just starts by querying sessions that were active at the top of each second.  Assuming the query that took the look took less than a second to run, it's entirely possible that it wouldn't have been caught in the initial sample.  Depending on how old this is, it could also have been lost when ASH downsampled the data.

Comment: @toddlermenot, we are experiencing same behaviour, have you found a solution to your problem or a reason that caused this?